# Magento 2: TinyMCE editor is breaking CMS directives nested in html attributes

Tags: magento2, tinymce

Using TinyMCE 3.4.7 (Magento 2) and I'm having an issue where when I insert Magento CMS directives into an html attribute, the resulting html ends up completely broken. For example:

```
<div data-img="{{view url="images/media/home/image1.jpg"}}"></div>
```

will be converted into:

```
<div data-img="{{view url="></div>
```

by the editor. Is there a way to get the TinyMCE editor to ignore everything inside the Magento curly brace {{  }} cms directives? Or another solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not valid. try use it as

```
<div data-img='{{view url="images/media/home/image1.jpg"}}'></div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I hear what you're saying, however: 1. When Magento replaces the directive with its proper content, the html WILL be valid 2. That's the way the insert widget/image button is inserting it. Your suggestion does work, however it won't be me entering the content, it will be people who won't be savvy about updating that after adding these directives